# Upgrading and Downgrading a subscription with proration Stripe Python

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments, integration

I am working on a Python application that uses the Stripe API for managing subscriptions. I offer several subscription plans at different price points, specifically $42 and $70.

I am trying to implement the following scenarios with Stripe's Python library and am looking for some assistance on how to proceed.

Scenario 1: Subscription Upgrade/Downgrade

When a user wants to change their subscription (either upgrade from the $42 plan to the $70 plan or downgrade from the $70 plan to the $42 plan), I want to calculate the amount they should be charged as follows:

New plan price - Old plan price - Prorated amount for the time they've already used the app.
I want this transaction to occur through a Stripe Checkout session.

Scenario 2: Billing Cycle Maintenance

Regardless of whether the user upgrades or downgrades their plan, I want their billing cycle to remain the same. So, for instance, if a user changes their subscription at 12:45 on 03/08/2023, they will pay the prorated difference immediately, and then on 03/09/2023 at 12:45, they would be charged the full price of their new subscription plan.

Any guidance on how to implement these scenarios would be greatly appreciated. Please note that I'm specifically looking for solutions that use the Stripe Python library.

Here's some of my existing code to give you an idea of my current approach:

```
@stripe_blueprint.route('/stripe/<string:product_id>/<string:recurring_type>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def stripe_payment(product_id, recurring_type):
    global sidebar_links
    user = None
    subscription_id = None
    expiry_date_timestamp_int = None

    # product_types = ['plan', 'addon', 'one_time','top_up']
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        user = load_user_or_sub(current_user)
        # if the user does not have a stripe customer id, create stripe customer
        customer_id = stripe.Customer.retrieve(user.stripe_customer_id)

        if customer_id.get('deleted') or not user.stripe_customer_id:
            logger.info(f'User {user.id} has a deleted stripe customer id or does not have a stripe customer id, creating one')
            create_stripe_customer(user)

    if PRODUCTS_JSON.get(product_id) is None:
        return abort(404)

    if recurring_type == 'monthly':
        price_id = PRODUCTS_JSON[product_id]['month']['id']

    elif recurring_type == "yearly":
        price_id = PRODUCTS_JSON[product_id]['year']['id']
    else:
        return abort(404)

    try:
        # Retrieve and update the subscription only if the user is authenticated and they have a valid subscription
        if user and user.stripe_subscription_id:
            subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(user.stripe_subscription_id)
            if subscription['status'] != 'canceled':

                # Assuming subscription_expiry_date is the string representation of your user's subscription expiry date
                subscription_expiry_date_str = user.subscription_expired_date
                # subscription_expiry_date_str = "03/08/2023 12:40"

                # Convert the string to a datetime object
                expiry_date_obj = datetime.strptime(subscription_expiry_date_str, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
                # Convert the datetime object to a Unix timestamp
                expiry_date_timestamp = time.mktime(expiry_date_obj.timetuple())

                # Convert the Unix timestamp to an integer
                expiry_date_timestamp_int = int(expiry_date_timestamp)


        checkout_session = checkout.Session.create(
            line_items=[{"price": price_id, "quantity": 1}],
            client_reference_id=user.user_hash_identifier if user else None,
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            mode="subscription",
            billing_address_collection='required',
            allow_promotion_codes=True,
            customer=user.stripe_customer_id if user else None,
            metadata={'recurring_type': recurring_type},
            subscription_data={"billing_cycle_anchor": expiry_date_timestamp_int, "proration_behavior": "create_prorations"} if expiry_date_timestamp_int else None,
            locale='auto',
            success_url=url_for('stripe_blueprint.order_success', _external=True) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=url_for('stripe_blueprint.order_cancel', _external=True),
            )
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f'User {user.id} failed to pay for {id} due to {e}')
        return str(e)

    return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)
```

Comment: Stripe Billing/Subscriptions API has a built in proration feature (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations) once applied, the proration amount will be deducted automatically from the customer's payment_method. Why you want the proration transaction occurs manually using Checkout Sessions ?

Comment: I need to show my user, how much he is going to pay, and not immediately charge him upon clicking on a button in my app, and I dont want to build my own charging UI that why I'm using Stripe.

Comment: In that case you will need to manage the proration and recurring payments on your integration and us one-time invoices for charging the customer:
https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration/quickstart
Or simply use Checkout Session for one time payments:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web
But you can't use Stripe Subscriptions API, you'll need to rebuild all the system by your own.

Comment: Any ideas of what's the ideal way to manage the prorations and recurring payments?
Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

> I need to show my user, how much he is going to pay, and not immediately charge him

Stripe has a native feature for previewing prorations without actually making any changes:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming

Considering a Customer with a Subscription `sub_x`, you can use this code to see the resulting Invoice if you made an update from an existing item `si_x` to a new Price `price_x`:

```
stripe.Invoice.upcoming(
   subscription=sub_x,
   subscription_items=[{'id':si_x, 'price':price_x}],
   subscription_proration_date=X
)
```

Something really important here is to set a `subscription_proration_date`, that you can then set as `proration_date` when you actually update your Subscription (otherwise the prorations items won't be the same).

More info:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations#preview-proration